# How to wrap the selected text in an angular paragraph with custom component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to wrap the selected text in div paragram which with a custom component.

I know we can wrap text in `<span>`, `<b>`, etc. tag using :

```
let selection = window.getSelection();
let range = selection?.getRangeAt(0);
let selectedText = selection?.toString();
range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(`<span>${selectedText}</span>`));
```

But how to wrap in a custom component of angular?
Let's say we have a component `SpecialComponent` with the selector as `<app-special>`

So DOM should be something like :

> Lorem Ipsum has been the `<app-special>`industry's standard dummy
> text ever since`</app-special>`the 1500s, when an unknown printer
> took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

Comment: Maybe <div [innerHTML]="someControllerStringWithHtmlTags"></div> ?

Comment: See: https://angular.io/guide/content-projection

Comment: @Brandon Content-projection will me pass the text content inside the component, but how will I inject the custom component in DOM in place of selected text?

Comment: @Deunz That won't help me inject the component over selected text.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're needing to accomplish. Content projection will allow you to wrap whatever content you want, e.g.: `<app-comp1>some <app-comp2>more</app-comp2> text</app-comp1>`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your custom component *SpecialComponent* has an input that takes a string parameter *customSentence*, then passing a string sentence into the component is done as follows:

```
Lorem Ipsum has been the 
<app-special [customSentence]="'industry's standard dummy text ever since'">
</app-special>
the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
make a type specimen book.
```

Within your custom component, create an input decorator to receive the sentence and a getter as follows:

```
private _customSentence: string = '';

...

@Input() 
set customSentence(value: string)
{
  this._customSentence = value;
}
get customSentence()
{
  return this._customSentence;
}
```

Your custom component HTML template will be:

```
<span>{{customSentence}}</span>
```

This will be sufficient to render your custom component within another component.